# Continuous Api calls with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, mern

Beginner web developer here I am creating a password manager and I thought it would be cool to create a chrome extension for it. So far I have been able to make progess but now I'm wondering if there's a more efficent way I can do it. I used set interval to constanty grab the id_token
(a jtw token) from the deployed site that is in local storage and then with the token I can make an api request to the graphl endpoint (the jwt is use in the bearer for auth). Like I said it works but in terms of perfoance and optimization I was wonder if there was a cleaning way to do things

I was think of using chrome.create.alarm but I want it so that the the user doesnt have to for instance log back into the chrome extension and to from my understanding creating the alarm requries some sort of button click and the minimum interval is 1 minute

```
export const getBearerKey = async () => {
  const deployedSite = await chrome.tabs.query({ url: 'https://passwordmanager-zep7.onrender.com/*' });
  const page = deployedSite[0];
  if (page) {
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
  target: { tabId: page.id },
  function: () => {
     setInterval(()=>{
    const token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
    chrome.storage.local.set({ bearerKey: token });
     },1000)

  },
});

  } 
};


export const checkLoginStatus = async (bearerKey) => {

      const graphqlEndpoint = 'https://passwordmanager-zep7.onrender.com/graphql';
      const graphqlQuery = `query Me {
        me {
          _id
          username
          email
          password {
            _id
            text
            length
            uppercase
            lowercase
            number
            specialCharacter
          }
          accounts {
            _id
            username
            email
            websiteUrl
            notes
            created
            updated
          }
        }
      }`;

      try {
        const response = await fetch(graphqlEndpoint, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${bearerKey}`
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            query: graphqlQuery,
          }),
        });

        const { data } = await response.json();
        chrome.storage.local.set({user:data})
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('GraphQL Error:', error);
      }
    }

import { checkAccounts } from "./api/checkAccounts.js"
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(details=>{
     setInterval(()=>{
getBearerKey()
  chrome.storage.local.get(['bearerKey'], (result) => {
    const {bearerKey}=result
    checkLoginStatus(bearerKey)
  });
       checkAccounts() 
     },1000)
      

})
```

Comment: The best method is to listen to the [storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event) event. Since this event is fired only in another document you can open it as an iframe inside the [offscreen document](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/). Your content script for this domain will need `all_frames` and you'll also check location.ancestorOrigins[0] === chrome.runtime.getURL('/').slice(0, -1)

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you so much it seems like this would fix my issues I was just wondering what order this should be done in and in what files?
I tried to first create a content script in both the manifest and then the actual file (I gave it the all frames permissions)
Then I went into the file to create the off the screen document
From there I was lost like where does `check location.ancestorOrigins[0] === chrome.runtime.getURL('/').slice(0, -1)` come in and should that if statement be have the storage event inside it ??? then do i execute the background script in background.js( serviceWorker)